Backpropgation for a single parameter on a rather simple network
Given the following network:

I'm asked to write the backpropagation process for the $b_3$ parameter, where the loss function is $L(y,z_3)=(z_3-y)^2$
I'm not supposed to calculate any of the weights or expressions, rather write a general term in terms of $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \beta}$
I'm also given that the starting term is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial b_3}$
I've thought about doing the following, which is basically: $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial b_3}=\frac{\partial L(b_3,z_3)}{\partial b_3}=\frac{\partial (z_3-b_3)^2}{\partial b_3}=2(b_3-z_3)$$
yet this feels off to me.

$y$ is not $b_3$. $\frac{\partial (z_3 - y)^2}{\partial b_3}$ is what you need to compute.

@noe in this, case, what is $y$?

$y$ is the expected output of the network.

I see, how can I use that to complete what needs to be done?

I guess that you should use backpropagation: apply the chain rule until you reach something where $b_3$ appears

Any chance for more elaboration? i dont seem to understand how to apply the chain rule here, i'm still learning this subject from scratch.

Can you find $\frac{\partial(z_3-y)^2}{\partial z_3}$? How about $\frac{\partial z_3}{\partial a_3}$?
